# SQL: Group by, order by time and show time in correct format

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new in SQL and I need to order and group by time. At the same time, I need to show in correct time format.

```
select test, total 
  from (
        select to_char(last_create_date, 'YYYYmm') as "test", count (seq) as "total"
          from public.newsfeed 
         group by to_char(last_create_date, 'YYYYmm')
         order by to_char(last_create_date, 'YYYYmm')) as T1
```

[image]

*But whenever I want to get the output as in `"MON YYYY"` format, I get the following error. How can I surpass? I have read through quite similar problems in stackoverflow already and they suggest to use sub-query or convert. But I don't know how to apply those into my case.*

```
 ERROR:  column "newsfeed.last_create_date" must appear in the GROUP BY
 clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: select test, total
 from (select to_char(last_create_date, 'M...
                                                 ^
 ********** Error **********

 ERROR: column "newsfeed.last_create_date" must appear in the GROUP BY
 clause or be used in an aggregate function SQL state: 42803 Character:
 41
```

Comment: @daniherrera yes, but he asks for `having output as "MON YYYY"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres allows you to use column aliases in the `select`.  So, you can write this as:

```
select to_char(last_create_date, 'YYYYmm') as test,
       count(seq) as total
from public.newsfeed 
group by test
order by min(last_create_date);
```

Note that ordering by the minimum of `last_create_date` puts the results in chronological order, rather than alphabetically by `test`.

This makes it easy to change the format:

```
select to_char(last_create_date, 'Mon YYYY') as test,
       count(seq) as total
from public.newsfeed 
group by test
order by min(last_create_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below with `'Mon YYYY'` format

```
select to_char(last_create_date, 'Mon YYYY') as "test", count (seq) as total
FROM public.newsfeed 
group by to_char(last_create_date, 'Mon YYYY')
order by to_char(last_create_date, 'Mon YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below no need subquery

```
    select to_char(last_create_date, 'MON YYYY') as "test",
    count(seq) as "total"
    FROM public.newsfeed 
    group by to_char(last_create_date, 'MON YYYY')
    order by to_char(last_create_date, 'MON YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

As error message refers you need to include non-aggregated column in the `GROUP BY` list as appears as in the `SELECT` list :

```
select t1.test, t1.total 
  from   
  (select to_char(last_create_date, 'MON YYYY') as test, count (seq) as "total"
     from public.newsfeed 
    group by to_char(last_create_date, 'MON YYYY')
    order by test 
  ) as t1;
```

But you ain't need to reform your `ORDER BY` clause with the exact format as `to_char(last_create_date, 'MON YYYY')` where you may use abbreviately *alias*(*`test`*) instead.

By the way you may replace count(seq) with `count(0)`, `count(1)`,`count(*)` or even `count(test)`..etc. they all give the same results for counting as long as you don't apply distinct such as `count(distinct test)`

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/OGJI98817)